# Copy numbers at the beginning of each line to the end of line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file that produces this kind of lines . I wanna edit these lines and put them in `passageiros.txt`

```
a82411:x:1015:1006:Adriana Morais,,,:/home/a82411:/bin/bash
a60395:x:1016:1006:Afonso Pichel,,,:/home/a60395:/bin/bash
a82420:x:1017:1006:Afonso Alves,,,:/home/a82420:/bin/bash
a69225:x:1018:1006:Afonso Alves,,,:/home/a69225:/bin/bash
a82824:x:1019:1006:Afonso Carreira,,,:/home/a82824:/bin/bash
a83112:x:1020:1006:Aladje Sanha,,,:/home/a83112:/bin/bash
a82652:x:1022:1006:Alexandre Ferreira,,,:/home/a82652:/bin/bash
a83063:x:1023:1006:Alexandre Feijo,,,:/home/a83063:/bin/bash
a82540:x:1024:1006:Ana Santana,,,:/home/a82540:/bin/bash
```

With the following code i'm able to get something like this:

```
cat /etc/passwd |grep "^a[0-9]" | cut -d ":" -f1,5 | sed "s/a//" | sed "s/,//g" > passageiros.txt
sed -e "s/$/:::a/" -i passageiros.txt


82411:Adriana Morais:::a
60395:Afonso Pichel:::a
82420:Afonso Alves:::a
69225:Afonso Alves:::a
82824:Afonso Carreira:::a
83112:Aladje Sanha:::a
82652:Alexandre Ferreira:::a
83063:Alexandre Feijo:::a
82540:Ana Santana:::a
```

So my goal is to create something like this:

```
82411:Adriana Morais:::a82411@
60395:Afonso Pichel:::a60395@
82420:Afonso Alves:::a82420@
69225:Afonso Alves:::a69225@
82824:Afonso Carreira:::a82824@
83112:Aladje Sanha:::a83112@
82652:Alexandre Ferreira:::a82652@
83063:Alexandre Feijo:::a83063@
82540:Ana Santana:::a82540@
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{val=$1;sub(/[a-z]+/,"",$1);print $1,$5,_,_,val"@"}' OFS=":" Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too.

```
awk -F'[:,]' '               ##Starting awk script here and making field seprator as colon and comma here.
{                            ##Starting main block here for awk.
  val=$1                     ##Creating a variable val whose value is first field.
  sub(/[a-z]+/,"",$1)        ##Using sub for substituting any kinf of alphabets small a to z in first field with NULL here.
  print $1,$5,_,_,val"@"     ##Printing 1st, 5th field and printing 2 NULL variables and printing variable val with @.
}                            ##Closing block for awk here.
' OFS=":" Input_file         ##Mentioning OFS value as colon here and mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***EDIT:*** Adding @Aserre's solution too here.

```
awk -F'[:,]' '{print substr($1, 2),$5,_,_,$1"@"}' OFS=":"  Input_file
```

Comment: 100% pure nitpicking, but you could do without the temp variable and write `'{print substr($1, 2),$5,_,_,$1"@"}'`. +1

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} {sub(/^a/, "", $1); gsub(/,/, "", $5); print $1, $5, _, _, "a" $1 "@"}' file > passageiros.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/xbHo7o)

**Details**

- `BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"}` sets the input and output field separator to `:`
- `sub(/^a/, "", $1)` removes the first `a` from Field 1
- `gsub(/,/, "", $5)` removes all `,` from Field 5
- `print $1, $5, _, _, "a" $1 "@"` prints only the necessary fields to the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one sed:

```
grep  '^a' file | cut -d: -f1,5 | sed 's/a\([^:]*\)\(.*\)/\1\2:::a\1@/;s/,,,//'
```